# Bind methods generated by filters

Tags: angularjs

I want to show a taglist

```
<td ng-bind-html="item.categories | totags"></td>
```

that is generated by the following filter filter

```js
angular.module('angularappApp')
.filter('totags', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var res = "";
        input.forEach(function(i) {
            res += '<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectCategory(\'' + i + '\')">' + i + '</a>';
        });
        return res;
    };
});
```

But `selectCategory` will never run on click. Is there way to bind clicks to methods generated by a filter?

Comment: Is there a reason for doing it not in directive?

Comment: Can I mark your comment as solved? ;=) Quick fingers...thanks!